# What are Different forms of a DNF (Disjunctive Normal Form)?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, disjunctive-normal-form

I've read somewhere that there are many forms of DNF (Disjunctive Normal Form) for each statement. Can you give me an example? For example given the statement: p.q + ~p.r  (which is in DNF) what other DNF forms are possible to write for this statement?
Thank you!

Comment: Well, you can always add terms that always evaluate to false, like $r \wedge \bar r$. I don't know if it is what the author say, though, but I don't see any other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three [Karnaugh maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) show three ways to represent your expression

[image]

The maps demonstrate how the four [minterms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_normal_form#Minterms) can be covered or grouped in terms with fewer variables:

$$qr \lor pq\bar{r} \lor \bar{p}\bar{q}r$$

$$pq \lor \bar{p}r$$

$$pqr \lor pq\bar{r} \lor \bar{p}\bar{q}r \lor \bar{p}qr$$

Each of these forms is a `DNF`, also called "sum of products".